# Why the newly installed template looks differently from the demo?

Tags: templates

I just installed a new template from http://themeforest.net/. My front end does not show all the components (banner, carousel, footer, etc.).

My Template:

[image]

My Frontend:

[image]

Can someone guide me how to customize my theme?

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely due to the fact that your previous template was using different module positions to the new template you are now using.

All you need to do is simply open each of the modules that are not displaying as they should and assign them to a position that belongs to your new template.

For example, the default Joomla 3.x template (Protostar) uses **position-7** for the right hand side, however another template may use **sidebar-a**.

To find out the module positions for your template have a look at the Demo and on the main menu, go to **Features** >> **Module Positions**:

http://demo.arrowthemes.com/?theme=legend

Hope this helps

Comment: For example, I need menu and banner to appear the way it is shown in the template above. Then what am i suppose to do? Do i have to go to their modules?

Comment: Yes, you will need to open "Main Menu" in the Module Manager and change the position to whatever name the template uses for the navbar. See the small update I have made to my answer

Comment: To be clear - no, you don't have to "go to their modules", but as Lodder says, you have to put *your* choice of module in the same *position* as their module.

Answer (score 2):

When installing a template into an existing Joomla install, it will never look like the demo of the new template. This is because all you've installed is the template itself and none of the demo materials. Unlike some other CMS's, most templates do NOT have things like carousel's built into them.

You have several choices:

1. Start from scratch and see if the theme designer has a full demo package installer. This is a Joomla installer package that is a full copy of their demo, including all data, setup, extensions, etc. You will lose ALL of your data if you do this, but it will give you the full site that IS their demo
2. See if they have a demo installer, but install it somewhere else (or through a mamp/wamp/xamp app) so you can use it as a reference to set your site up to match it
3. See if the theme designer has instructions on how to set up your site to match their demo.